# Find alternative path with exclusion between two vertices using SQL in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I am a rookie and I try to understand and become involved in this techno.

My problem is simple but i can not find the solution. I need your help. 
Here is a graph. I want to find the sum of the nodes between the two vertices.

I would like to have:

## 50:0 #60:0 #63:0 #51:0 = 10620

## 50:0 #64:0 #65:0 #51:0 = 14102

I used shortestPath()

However I want to find an alternative path when I want to exclude some node, e.g. #60:0 or #63:0

***The sum of the nodes must be only between @class=V1***

Many thanks in advance for your assistance, and I am looking forward to hearing from you.

[image: Graph]

[image: Path]

```
SELECT sum(outE('E1').distance) as distance FROM (
SELECT expand(path) FROM (
  SELECT shortestPath(#50:0, #51:0) AS path 
  )
  )
```

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using?

Comment: OrientDB version : 2.2.34